# how to make python code return as false if no data is entered when using "in" command

Tags: python, windows

I am fairly new to python and would like some help.
I am trying to write a program which checks if something is an allowed option and it would continuously repeat. I have got this far:

```
menu=input("Enter options:")
def text():
    x = 1
    while x == 1:
        request = input("Chosen option:")
        print(request.lower() in menu.lower())
    text()
```

and it works. I get asked for the possible options, i enter them, then it asks for my chosen option, i enter it and if it is one of them it returns "True" and if it is not, it returns "False". However, if I don't input anything and instead just press enter, it also returns "True", which I do not want to happen. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.[I attached a picture of the code, it doesn't make a difference how I enter the options (spaces, commas, no gap, etc) i still get the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL9Hy.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posted code has syntax errors due to improper indentation, and no `return` to produce the effect you describe.  It also depends on variable input.

Comment: Please do not attach pictures of code, just copy&paste the code into your question directly. This allows others to copy&paste it into their editors and helps them answer your questions.

Comment: If you are trying to run an infinite loop, you can just do `while True` versus defining 'x = 1' and checking `while x == 1`.  Also, your posted code has an indent before `text()` that it appears should not be there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you define `menu`. `menu` in your case is a string (I suspect you are on python3, in python2 `input()` does some "magic" like converting `"3"` (a string) to `3` (an integer)). If you then provide no input for `request` you essentially have the following code:

```
"" in "foo,bar"
```

The empty string `""` is in every string, so it is always in your options string.

You can translate your options to a list of options instead of having a single string:

```
>>> menu = input().split(",")
>>> print(menu)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

assuming you entered `a,b,c`. Now `""` is not in this list so it fixes your problem.